# How to transition from walk to run animation in Unity?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, maya

I've gone and used my own method but I'm not getting the desired results - I need to know how to properly transition from a single step walk animation to a continuous run cycle animation via C# in Unity. I've looked on Unity forums but no dice.

Alright, so I've created an idle and a continuous walk animation in Maya and imported into Unity - I then cut the walk cycle into 2 individual steps (1 left and 1 right).

Because my character moves one step at a time depending on the user's tapping (he only starts "running" or walking continuously when the user keeps tapping), I just alternate every other step with the left and right animations using a trigger in my animation controller.

Here is my current setup (the transitions are the L and R triggers):

[image]

And then the code:

```
public swipes swipe() {
    if (Input.touches.Length > 0) {
        Touch t = Input.GetTouch (0);

if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began && CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButton ("Swipe")) {
    if (stepCount % 2 != 0) {
        animator.SetTrigger ("oneStep");
        stepCount++;
    } else {
        animator.SetTrigger ("twoStep");
        stepCount++;
    }
    return swipes.tap;
    }
}}
```

And this looks Ok, but only when the user is periodically tapping, meaning not tapping multiple times successively. When they tap rapidly, the steps all blend together and animations are too slow to finish, so it looks unnatural and not like running.

What I need to do is if the taps start coming in rapid succession transition to my full pre-made run cycle instead of the individual steps. I have some ideas obviously but I cant be the only one to run into this - what is the proper way to orchestrate this?

How can I correctly go from single steps to walk animation?